# mongodb & java update array

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb

I want to do some kind of log tool.
my json structure will be like this.

```
{
_ObjectId:1
"sessionId":
"room":"oda1"
"roomType":
"attendees": {
        {   
        "userObjectid":"1" ???
        "userId":
        "userDisplay":
        "userAuthority":
        "activities": {
                {
                "activity":"1"  //1:joined
                "timestamp":"1.1.1.1.1"
                "result":"1"
                        },
                {
                "activity":"2"  //2:disconnect
                "timestamp":"1.1.1.1.1"
                "result":"1"
                        },
                  }
        },
        {   
        "userObjectid":"1" ???
        "userId":
        "userDisplay":
        "userAuthority":
        "activities": {
                {
                "activity":"1"  //1:joined
                "timestamp":"1.1.1.1.1"
                "result":"1"
                        },
                {
                "activity":"2"  //2:disconnect
                "timestamp":"1.1.1.1.1"
                "result":"1"
                        },
                  }
        }
         }
}
```

My code works fine when create data for the first time.
Data should be updated while user do some activities(like join,quit (A tuple should have all session data.))
while update the data my code create new tag with named activities.

```
 {ROOM=testo@conference.demo.com.tr, ROOM_TYPE=null, SESSION_ACTIVE=true, USERS={ "0" : { "ACTIVITIES" : [ { "RESULT" : "1" , "ACTIVITY" : "quit" , "TIMESTAMP" : { "$date" : "2016-07-26T12:12:09.518Z"}}]} , "ACTIVITIES" : { "RESULT" : "1" , "ACTIVITY" : "join" , "TIMESTAMP" : "Tue Jul 26 15:11:51 EEST 2016"} , "USERID" : "535e7387" , "USER_AUTHORITY_TYPE" : "Owner" , "USER_DISPLAY_NAME" : "focus"}, _id=57975388a297be1c19460557}
```

Here is my update code:

```
try {

            DBCollection table = connectDB().getCollection("SESSIONS");
            BasicDBObject sessionDetail = new BasicDBObject();
            sessionDetail.put("ROOM", room);
            sessionDetail.put("SESSION_ACTIVE", true);
            sessionDetail.put("USERS.USERID", userName);
            Map<String, Object> activityDetail = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            //BasicDBObject activityDetail = new BasicDBObject();
            activityDetail.put("ACTIVITY", "quit");
            activityDetail.put("TIMESTAMP", new Date());
            activityDetail.put("RESULT", "1");

             BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject();
                data.put("$push", new BasicDBObject("USERS.0.ACTIVITIES", activityDetail));



                table.update(sessionDetail, data,true,true);
```

Also i get error change "USERS.0.ACTIVITIES" to "USERS.ACTIVITIES". Why 0 is necessary for this?
i do many research but couldn't find solution about it.
Could anyone help me please ?

Comment: it's a subdocument : USERS.$.ACTIVITIES

Comment: It looks like the JSON object you're creating doesn't have the structure that you're expecting. When I format the JSON `{ROOM=testo@conference ... }` I can see that the `USERS` field is an object with a field called `0` which is itself a JSON object with a field `ACTIVITIES` that appears to be an array containing activity information. Can you check the JSON structure that your'e adding to make sure it is formatted as you expect?

Comment: Slim i got that error when use " USERS.$.ACTIVITIES" "Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array".

Comment: @Jerod you are right my json format is not my excepted. this is my add data function result <code> {_id=57976268a297be1c1946055d, ROOM=test@conference.demo.com.tr, ROOM_TYPE=null, SESSION_ACTIVE=true, USERS={ "USER_AUTHORITY_TYPE" : "Owner" , "ACTIVITIES" : { "RESULT" : "1" , "ACTIVITY" : "join" , "TIMESTAMP" : "Tue Jul 26 16:15:12 EEST 2016"} , "USER_DISPLAY_NAME" : "focus" , "USERID" : "4864f1dd"}}</code>  when i call update method "0" comes. i dont want use jsons in my java code. javadriver 3.0 jar methods arent  enough for my operations ?

Comment: @oguz The `$push` operator is used to add an item to an array (see: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/). Based on your comment, `ACTIVITIES` isn't an array, so it won't work as you expect. Can you restructure your collection so that `ACTIVITIES` is an array?